# Erro com botões de navegação

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estou tentando fazer com que ao clicar em um botão 'confirmar', ele vá pra outra tela (login) mas me deparo com o seguinte erro:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_this2.props.navigation.navigate') onPress
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\src\screens\Register.js:33:57 touchableHandlePress
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\TouchableNativeFeedback.android.js:187:45
>   _performSideEffectsForTransition
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:803:34
>   _receiveSignal
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:717:44
>   touchableHandleResponderRelease
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:435:24
>   invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:93:15
>   invokeGuardedCallback
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:318:36
>   invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:342:30
>   executeDispatch
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:715:42
>   executeDispatchesInOrder
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:737:20
>   executeDispatchesAndRelease
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:894:29
>   executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:902:37
>   forEachAccumulated
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:874:16
>   runEventsInBatch
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:1050:21
>   runExtractedEventsInBatch
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:1072:19
>   
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2711:6
>   batchedUpdates$1
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17075:14
>   batchedUpdates
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2614:31
>   _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2709:17
>   receiveTouches
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2785:28
>   __callFunction
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:349:47
>   
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:106:26
>   __guard
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:297:10
>   callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       C:\Users\DevUp\meuApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:105:17

Não sei o que fazer, já procurei e procurei mas não resolveu o meu caso

código da Tela de Registro abaixo:

E já criei a tela de Login

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'

import {
    View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput

} from 'react-native'

class Register extends Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={StyleSheet.container}>
                <TextInput placeholder="Name" style={styles.input}
                    autoFocus={true} keyboardType='name'
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChangeText={name => this.setState({ name })} />
                <TextInput placeholder="Email" style={styles.input}
                    autoFocus={true} keyboardType='email-address'
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })} />

                <TextInput placeholder='Password' style={styles.input}
                    secureTextEntry={true} value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })} />

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onPress.navigation.navigate('Login')} style={styles.buttom}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttomText}>Confirm</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',

    },
    buttom: {

        marginTop: 15,
        marginLeft: '25%',
        backgroundColor: '#4286f4',
        borderRadius: 5,
        padding: 10,
        width: '50%'

    },
    buttomText: { 
    fontSize: 15,
    color: '#FFF',
    textAlign: 'center'

    },
    text: {
        marginTop: 5,
        fontSize: 15,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    input: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginTop: 20,
        marginLeft: '10%',
        width: '80%',
        backgroundColor: '#EEE',
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#333',
    }
})

export default Register
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa!
Erro de sintaxe em:

```
 this.props.onPress.navigation.navigate('Login')
```

Mude para :

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
```

Qualquer dúvida :

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html

Comment: Opa, então já tinha tentado isso e o problema insistiu em aparecer

Comment: O mesmo erro? creio que se aparecer erro seja diferente. Você já criou a rota de login lá no RootStack do seu Navigator ? pode também tentar acessar via função, no onPress chame uma função e nela chame a navegação. E coloque um console.warn para ver se o clique está chegando até a função..

Answer (score 0):

Fiz umas mudanças no seu código e coloquei uma explicação em baixo

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native'

class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={StyleSheet.container}>
        <TextInput placeholder="Name" style={styles.input}
          autoFocus={true} keyboardType='name'
          value={this.state.name}
          onChangeText={name => this.setState({ name })} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Email" style={styles.input}
          autoFocus={true} keyboardType='email-address'
          value={this.state.email}
          onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })} />
        <TextInput placeholder='Password' style={styles.input}
          secureTextEntry={true} value={this.state.password}
          onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })} />

        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={styles.buttom}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}>
          <Text style={styles.buttomText}>Confirm</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Nesse caso, estou assumindo que você possui um StackNavigator com a sua tela 'Login' e a sua tela 'Register'
Por exemplo:

```
const Exemplo = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: Login,
    Register: Register
  },
  {
  initialRouteName: "Login"
  }
);
```

Para que o this.props.navigation.navigate('Login') funcione, você precisa ter a tela de login dentro de um stackNavigator. Esse stackNavigator pode ficar no seu App.js ou em algum arquivo separado para cuidar da sua navegação no aplicativo.